# How to click on an image in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to click on an image on web page.
Xpath for this image is:

```
//*[@id='gridview-1018']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[7]/div/a/img
```

HTML code is:

```
<td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1016 ">`<div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: center; ;">`<a href="http://demo.webshopondemand.com/Shop/AbzorbDevelopment/Store/" target="_blank">`<img src="/admin/templates/images/house.png" style="background-color: transparent;"/>`
```

Tried all the below methods here, but got the same error msg "Unable to locate the element:

1. `driver`.findElement(`By`.`xpath`(".//*[@id='gridview-1018']/table/`tbody`/tr[3]/td[7]/div/a/img")).click();
2. WebElement temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'/admin/templates/images/house.png')]"));
   temp.click();
3. `WebDriverWait` wait = new `WebDriverWait`(driver, 60);
   wait.until(`ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated`(`By.cssSelector`("x-grid-cell-inner.a.img")));
   `driver.findElement`(`By.cssSelector`("x-grid-cell-`inner.a.img")).click()

4.`driver`.`findElement`(By.cssSelector`("a[href='AbzorbDevelopment']")).click();

Thanks for the help[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please use Actions class with below syntax

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(xpath).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Thanks Raj for your reply. I tried following code:                      WebElement shop = driver.findElement((By.xpath("//*[@id='gridview-1018']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[7]/div/a/img")));
 Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
 actions.moveToElement(shop).click().perform();                      Received error msg: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='gridview-1018']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[7]/div/a/img"}

Comment: Received error msg: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='gridview-1018']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[7]/d‌​iv/a/img"}

Comment: means your xpath is invalid plz try to give valid xpath it will surely work

Comment: xpath  is .//*[@id='gridview-1018']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[7]/div/a/img

Comment: form here i cannot validate your xpath as i donot have source code of your page if possible provide me the link

Comment: also plz try to identify if there is any iframe on your web application

Comment: I am not able to send any image, screenshot. Can you pls provide me ur email id to send these details?

Answer (score 0):

Do as what raj said i.e.
use Actions class

`Actions act = Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(xpath).click().build().perform();`

But instead of such absolute xpath, can you try for CSS as given below:

```css
div.x-grid-cell-inner>a[href='http://demo.webshopondemand.com/Shop/AbzorbDevelopment/Store/']>img[src='/admin/templates/images/house.png']
```

your final implementation will be like:

```
WebElement shop = driver.findElement((By.css("div.x-grid-cell-inner>a[href='http://demo.webshopondemand.com/Shop/AbzorbDevelopment/Store/']>img[src='/admin/templates/images/house.png']")));
```

Actions actions = new Actions(driver); 
actions.moveToElement(shop).click().build().perform();

Please note: above css path is created based on source code you had given in your question.